# Is playing a game that has gambling/drinking etc

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol, game, gambling, pornography

Is it haram to play a game called read dead redemption 2 that has gambling drinking alcohol and if I go to a hotel or a bar there’s rooms I was in a mission to look for someone so I was looking for the person then I went inside the rooms I found pornography inside there and I closed my monitor instantly after that I continued to play the game is that haram and sinful please reply fast so I can tell my friends not to play it if it is.

Answer (score 0):

The answer: **It's best to stay away from games that draw away from what's halal and haram.**

Judging by what you've told us, it seems apparent it's full of a lot of filth. With too much exposure to that, it may influence you to sin (not to mention you would be sinning by exposing yourself to all this fitnah even in a game (you've even mentioned you've found porn in the game). It's best to surround yourself with games that aren't too sinful and stay away from games that contain a lot of haram content (and violence).

Allah knows best.